# Cannot build library in subdirectory when top-level CMakeLists.txt calls install(EXPORT)

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to add a feature as a sub-library to
an existing application. But I met troubles of `install(EXPORT ...)`

My project source code structure shows as below:

```
app (the existing application)
     |-- top-level CMakeLists.txt
     |
     |-- sublib (my new feature)
     |        |-- src
     |        |-- include
     |        `-- CMakeLists.txt
     |
     |-- other existing src ...
```

I build **sublib** in the *CMakeLists.txt* inside my own feature as:

```
add_library(sublib ${LIB_SRC})
```

I modify the top-level *CMakeLists.txt* in the existing application to
link **sublib**:

```
add_subdirectory(subdirectory of sublib)
...
target_link_directories(app sublib)
```

I thought it was enough. But CMake threw out an error:

> CMake Error: install(EXPORT "appTargets" ...) includes target "app"
>   which requires target "sublib" that is not in the export set.

I guess it is because **app** itself is exported by `install(EXPORT .. )` in the
top-level *CMakeLists.txt*. Thus I also try to install and export **sublib**.
I add the install and export into **sublib** *CMakeLists.txt*:

```
install(TARGETS sublib
    EXPORT  sublibTargets
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${BIN_INSTALL_DIR}
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${LIB_INSTALL_DIR}
    RUNTIME DESTINATION ${LIB_INSTALL_DIR}
    )

install(EXPORT sublibTargets
    FILE sublib-config.cmake
    DESTINATION ${LIB_INSTALL_DIR}/cmake/sublib
    )
```

I then add `find_package()` in top-level *CMakeLists.txt*:

```
find_package(sublib REQUIRED)
target_link_directories(app sublib)
```

However, it becomes worse. **sublib** is never built at all and
*sublib-config.cmake* is not found.
I manually set the `PATHS` to *sublib-config.cmake* in `find_package()` but it still failed.

Could you please tell me how fix the EXPORT issue?

Thank you.

Best regards,
David Hu

Comment: Why do you call `find_package(sublib)` in your top-level `CMakeLists.txt`?

Comment: Hi @piwi, it seems that top-level CMakeLists.txt is unable to recognize sublib if they are exported.

Comment: I add `target_include_directoris()` into my **sublib** _CMakeLists.txt_ and modify the install/export commands as `install(TARGETS sublib EXPORT sublibConfig ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${LIB_INSTALL_DIR} LIBRARY DESTINATION ${LIB_INSTALL_DIR}) export(TARGETS sublib FILE sublibConfig.cmake ) install(EXPORT sublibConfig DESTINATION ${LIB_INSTALL_DIR}/sublib/cmake)` Now the **sublib** can be built and _sublibConfig.cmake_ seems to be found. However an error still occurs: **The following imported targets are referenced, but are missing: sublib**

Answer (score 0):

You should not have to call `find_package(sublib)` in your top-level `CMakeLists.txt`, this is intended to be used by a project that uses `sublib` once it is installed. Because you call `add_subdirectory(sublib)` in your `CMakeLists.txt`, the target `sublib` is already available where you call `target_link_directories(app sublib)`.

Comment: Hi @piwi, the key point is install(EXPORT...) in top-level CMakeLists.txt. As you point out, the building succeeds if I remove the install(EXPORT) from top-level CMakeLists.txt. With install(EXPORT), the sublib is unavailable since it.is.not.exported

Comment: It is `find_package(sublib)` that you have to remove from your top-level CMakeLists.txt, not `install(EXPORT)`, or I did not understand your problem.

Comment: I tried removing find_package(). However, the sublib is neither linked. I wonder if there is any formal tutorial of EXPORT in cmake. The CMake documents are just small pieces.

Comment: Can you share the error you get when you remove find_package()?

Comment: Hi @piwi. I add `target_include_directoris()` into my **sublib** _CMakeLists.txt_ and modify the install/export commands as
`install(TARGETS sublib
    EXPORT  sublibConfig
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${LIB_INSTALL_DIR}
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${LIB_INSTALL_DIR}
)
export(TARGETS sublib
    FILE sublibConfig.cmake
)
install(EXPORT sublibConfig
    DESTINATION ${LIB_INSTALL_DIR}/sublib/cmake
)`
Now the **sublib** can be built and _sublibConfig.cmake_ seems to be found. However an error still occurs: **The following imported targets are referenced, but are missing: sublib**

Answer (score 0):

I tried to answer it by myself. I'm inspired by @piwi.

If the **sublib** is put under **app** as a sub-directory, **sublib** source code should be built together with those of **app**, rather than treating **sublib** as an standalone library. No need to export **sublib**.

Export and install of **sublib** is only necessary when **sublib** is placed as an independent library. Export and install the **sublib** in **sublib** *CMakeLists.txt*. Put a *Findsublib.cmake* under app's `cmake/modules`. Thus later when **app** *CMakeLists.txt* call `find_package(sublib)`, `Findsublib.cmake` tells **app** how to find out **sublib** and build or link **sublib**